# How to resolve API deprecations in ios7?

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios7

What is the best way to resolve deprecations? I want my application to also work with older versions such as 6.0.

I have some code like this:

```
[leftButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor blueColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

it is showing warning UITextAttributTextColor is deprecated. However things work just fine on ios7.

Now should I write version specific code (different code for 7.0 and prior versions?

I can easily resolve the warnings, but then I am afraid, it wouldn't work with prior versions. If I write separate blocks (as shown below), warning stays in the code. What is the best way to handle such situation?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0"))
{
    // code here for iOS 5.0,6.0 and so on
    textLabelSize = [tmp sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONTNAME size:FONTSIZE]];
}
else
{
    // code here for iOS 7.0
    textLabelSize = [tmp sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName: FONTNAME size:FONTSIZE]}];
        
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just leave it there and change it when some future version actually removes the deprecations and marks it as error.

Comment: I'll second this approach if your reason is to support older versions of iOS.  The point of deprecating a feature is to keep people from using it in *new* code.  I expect a deprecated feature to work until at least the next version of iOS and by the time that happens it might make sense to drop support for the older version anyway.

Comment: Leaving it as it is is actually a very bad advice. Yes you can update it as soon as some future iOS release breaks it but you can not rely on your update being available on day 1. This will make your app crash for all users that do not have the version of your app installed that fixes the issue. This leads to a very bad user experience IMHO. They warn you way ahead of time so make use of that warning and fix your code before it breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode tells you what to do; use `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`.

[image]

Comment: yes, that is right. But if i follow that, wouldn't it stop working on prior versions? if so, then do i need to write version specific code? i have added example code in comment section above? is that approach good?

Comment: @AsmaZ the declaration for `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` shows it was introduced in iOS 6, so there's no problem.